# How to make an option selected from a dropdown list in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

In my project. I want to populate the drop down list on a jsp from a database.

```
<select id="names" name="names"> <c:forEach items="${names}" var="names">
        <option><c:out value="${names}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The `${names}` is a list of names from the database. I want to select an option dynamically in the drop down list. Suppose there are three names in the database Rohan, Dean, Justin. If Dean is logged, i want select the option Dean as selected.

I try a code like this but this does not work.

```
<option value="${names}" ${names == names ? 'selected' : ''}>${names}</option>
```

Comment: You could post the code showing what have you tried. This is better than just asking how to do the things.

Comment: Comparing strings should be done with `equals()` not with `==`

Comment: And `names == names` is useless...

Comment: First, you should change the name of that local `names` var to `name`, just for easier maintenance. Second, you're comparing `names` with `names` (and you should use `equals` to compare `String` variables), like `1 == 1`, you should compare the `name` variable with a request or session parameter that handles the actual userName or another variable you want/need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this assuming that loggedInUser variable holds the String value of the currently logged in user.

```
<select id="names" name="names">
<c:forEach items="${names}" var="names">

    <c:when test="${loggedInUser eq names}">    
        <option value ="<c:out value="${names}"/>" selected="selected">${names}</option>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <option><c:out value="${names}"/></option> 
    </c:otherwise>  
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You should point that `loggedInUser` is a String request parameter as well and it is available at that moment.

Comment: Based in the OP posted code, it looks like he/she still has problems in that area.